# How can I instantiate an object in jUnit, that needs to reflectively create another object inside its constructor?

Tags: java, reflection, junit, instance, invocationtargetexception

I'm trying to write a junit test for one of my classes. The design was not done by me; this is a fairly old application, java7, struts1, and clydeDB framework.

The classes are set up like this:
`ProcessObj`, 
`IProcessObj` (interface),
`ProcessHome`,

```
public class ProcessHome {

   private static ProcessHome instance = new ProcessHome();

   //default Constructor
   private ProcessHome() {
   }

   public static ProcessHome getInstance() {
      return instance;
   }

   public IProcessObj getProcessObj() throws POException {
      return ProcessObj.getInstance(); //this is below
   }
}

public class ProcessObj implements IProcessObj {
   // instance
   private static IProcessObj instance;
   ...
   //constuctor
   private ProcessObj() throws POException {
      init();
   }

   static IProcessObj getInstance() throws POException {
      if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ProcessObj();
      }
      return instance;
   }
   //jUnit test setUp

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {

      public static IProcessObj iPO;
      iPAO = ProcessHome.getInstance()
            .ProcessObj();

      Constructor<ProcessObj> pa = ProcessObj.class
            .getDeclaredConstructor();
      pa.setAccessible(true);
      iPO = pa.newInstance();`

     ...
```

It works fine up to here, but then in the `ProcessObj`, the initialization method goes through another set of classes that are set up exactly like the process objects that are above, for the data access layer.

Is there a way that I can create a usable instance of the process object? Can someone explain to me what exactly is going on here? I keep getting a `InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: The InvocationTargetException occurs on calling `newInstance`, right? This means that the constructor (and as you assume the method `init`) throws and Exception (which you could find by invoking `getCause` on the InvocationTargetException. Since the contents of `init` are not available to us, you will have to track this cause Exception down.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't do something like this:

```
public class ProcessHome {

   private static ProcessHome instance = new ProcessHome();

   //default Constructor
   private ProcessHome() {
   }

   public static ProcessHome getInstance() {
      return instance;
   }

   public IProcessObj getProcessObj() throws POException {
      return ProcessObj.getInstance(); //this is below
   }
}

public class ProcessObj implements IProcessObj {
   // instance
   private static IProcessObj instance;
   ...
   //constuctor
   private ProcessObj() throws POException {
      init();
   }

   static IProcessObj getInstance() throws POException {
      if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ProcessObj();
      }
      return instance;
   }


//jUnit test class


public class ProcessHomeTest {
    private IProcessObj iPO = ProcessHome.getInstance()
            .ProcessObj();

   @Test
   public void testIProcessObj() throws Exception {
         //use iPO heretest iPO
    assertEquals("some","some");
    }
```

Comment: Hi Salc2 - thanks for the quick reply. unfortunately, this will not work for me. in the constructor of ProcessObj, there is another call to get an instance of a different object, the data access object. I would like to know if there is a way to mock it up

Comment: @jerryn44 ok now I understand, well maybe if `IProcessObj` is an interface so you could implement it in an instancing of an anonymous class and use this object as a mock. But I don't know if that would be a good practice.